# Modifying or adding classes to individual components within core wordpress blocks

Tags: javascript, wordpress, reactjs, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I am having difficulty modifying or adding additional classes to individual components of wordpress blocks. I essentially just want to add a class or classes to some of the pieces that make up some of the core wordpress blocks to do things like add bootstrap styling.

An example of this would be the image gallery block. It works well enough for my purposes, but I may want to do something like add an "img-fluid" or "img-thumbnail" class to the images that are within that gallery.

I have looked through the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/filters/block-filters/) for block filters and I feel as though my answer is going to lie somewhere in there, I'm just not sure where yet.

I have tried using the [blocks.getBlockDefaultClassName](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/filters/block-filters/#blocks-getblockdefaultclassname) filter, but this adds a classname to the entire block as opposed to individual pieces that make up that block (such as the images in my gallery example).

This is the example they give for it in the documentation:

```
 // Our filter function
function setBlockCustomClassName( className, blockName ) {
    return blockName === 'core/code' ?
        'my-plugin-code' :
        className;
}

// Adding the filter
wp.hooks.addFilter(
    'blocks.getBlockDefaultClassName',
    'my-plugin/set-block-custom-class-name',
    setBlockCustomClassName
);
```

I feel as though [blocks.getSaveContent.extraProps](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/filters/block-filters/#blocks-getsavecontent-extraprops) might do what I need it to, but I am not sure how to use it in this way. The example they use looks like this:

```
function addBackgroundColorStyle( props ) {
    return lodash.assign( props, { style: { backgroundColor: 'red' } } );
}

wp.hooks.addFilter(
    'blocks.getSaveContent.extraProps',
    'my-plugin/add-background-color-style',
    addBackgroundColorStyle
);
```

But even if I were to add an extra property like a class name, I would think I would then need to modify the actual save and edit functions (I guess using more block filters) to then use that class name when it displays those pieces (in this case - the images), and I'm also not sure how to do that.

Any thoughts or suggestions about this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are two kind of changes one is structural change and the other one is styling change. In your scenario you need styling change but you are actually looking for structural change. You can write your own CSS that can handles your block styling on editor view and on front end.

These are the hooks that you need to enqueue your styles [enqueue_block_editor_assets](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/enqueue_block_editor_assets/) (enqueue your styles only on backend editor) and [enqueue_block_assets](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/enqueue_block_assets/) (enqueue your styles on both backend and frontend).

Comment: Well I want to change the actual class names or add additional class names to the elements so I can utilize bootstrap styling. It doesn't make sense to me to essentially recreate a particular bootstrap style and put it in my css just under a different name - especially since I'm using bootstrap throughout other parts of the site. That's why I'm looking for a way to just add additional class names to elements inside of the core blocks.

Comment: Unfortunately the images inside gallery blocks are not blocks (as they are in columns block) so you have to write your custom block as no filter can help you in this.

On the other hand you can add a column block and add images on it if it serves your purpose.